# std::invoke_result on std::tie

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using GCC 7.3 with C++17 and I do not understand why this line is failing:

```
template <typename... Args>
using X = std::invoke_result<std::tie, Args...>::type;
```

Error is:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _ArgTypes> 
struct std::invoke_result’
using X = std::invoke_result<std::tie, Args...>::type;
note:   expected a type, got ‘std::tie’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all in the error message:

> note:   expected a type, got ‘std::tie’

[`invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is a metafunction that takes a bunch of *types*. [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is a *function template* - it's not a type. And it's not even an object, so you cannot do `invoke_result<decltype(std::tie), Args...>` either.

What `invoke_result` gives you is one syntax that works for all kinds of callables. But you don't need that with `std::tie` - it's a function template, so you can just directly invoke it in an unevaluated context:

```
template <typename... Args>
using X = decltype(std::tie(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

---

Note: Unless you really, specifically need the metafunction itself, just always use the `_t` alias. That is, `std::invoke_result_t<...>` rather than `std::invoke_result<...>::type`. The latter is wrong anyway, since you're missing the `typename` keyword - and the alias obviates that need.